# How can i use python to convert sensor data (1,200,9) to (9,200,1)?

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

The shape of sensor data is (1,200,9),the number of channel is 9,but i want to convert it to a 2-D data which the channel is 1, and the final shape is (9,200,1). I have test  keras.layers.core.Reshape((9,200,1)), but there has error. So i don't know what should i do, i hope someone can help me,thank you very much.

Comment: `tuple(list((1, 200, 9))[::-1])`
> Simple is better than complexe (`import this`)

Comment: @Abdelouahab  oh my god, it works, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

If you do it while you are treating your data. You can use numpy [`swapaxes`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html). Example from documentation:

```
>>> x = np.array([[[0,1],[2,3]],[[4,5],[6,7]]])
>>> x
array([[[0, 1],
        [2, 3]],
       [[4, 5],
        [6, 7]]])

>>> np.swapaxes(x,0,2)
array([[[0, 4],
        [2, 6]],
       [[1, 5],
        [3, 7]]])
```

However, if you're using it for transformation of one of your training layers, you have to use either tensorflow [`transpose`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/transpose) function, or an analog function in your deep learning framework.

```
x = tf.constant([[[ 1,  2,  3],
                  [ 4,  5,  6]],
                 [[ 7,  8,  9],
                  [10, 11, 12]]])

tf.transpose(x, perm=[0, 2, 1])  # [[[1,  4],
                                 #   [2,  5],
                                 #   [3,  6]],
                                 #  [[7, 10],
                                 #   [8, 11],
                                 #   [9, 12]]]
```

In your case, since we are talking about the input of your system, you should use `np.swapaxes` for the preprocessing step.

Comment: At first, thank you very much for your help. I use keras to build a cnn model, the input is (1,200,9), i use np.swapaxes to convert sensor data, but there is an error 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'swapaxes', so how could i convert tensor shape?

Comment: If your input has shape ` (1,200,9)`, you have to preprocess your data before passing it to keras, which means, you do the function `swapaxes` before passing to a keras variable.